# Nativescript - Pass array from home-view-model to home.js

Tags: nativescript

I´m having a hard time understanding how to perform this action(as the title says), and maybe someone could help me understand the process, my code is below:

**My home-view-model:**

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var http = require("http");

function createViewModel() {

    http.getJSON("http://myJsonfile").then(function (r) {
        var arrNoticias = new ObservableArray(r.data);
        return arrNoticias;

    }, function (e) {

    });
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

I have done a console.log of the arrNoticias **before** i have putted it inside a callback function and it returns [object object] etc...and then i have done this:

**console.log(arrNoticias.getItem(0).titulo);**

and it returns the info i need!.

**Then in my home.js file i have this:**

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable")
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var arrNoticias = require('./home-view-model.js');

console.log(arrNoticias.getItem(0).titulo);
```

and the result in the console is:

**TypeError: arrNoticias.getItem is not a function. (In 'arrNoticias.getItem(0)', 'arrNoticias.getItem' is undefined)**

My question is, how does this action is perform? passing the data from view-model to the .js file?

Thanks for your time
  Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As that function send a URL request so probably it's an async function, which is on hold while requesting so that's why you get undefined. Normally, you will want your function that sends a URL request to return a promise. Based on that promise, you will the result as expected after the request is done. So:

```
function createViewModel() {
    return new Promise<>((resolve, reject) => {
        http.getJSON("http://myJsonfile").then(function (r) {
            var arrNoticias = new ObservableArray(r.data);
            resolve(arrNoticias);
        }, function(e) {
            reject(e);
        });
    }), (e) => {
        console.log(e);  
    })
}
```

In `home.js`:

```
var homeVM= require('./home-view-model.js');
var arrNoticias;

homeVM.createViewModel().then(function(r) {
    arrNoticias = r;
});
```

Comment: Hi Dinh Le, thank you for answering, but it´s not working, when i do console.log(arrNoticias); in the home.js, the console says: home.js:8:12: undefined

Comment: my log: home.js:12:12: undefined

Comment: Can you understand what is happening? i really don´t!!.

Comment: I think the problem is that somehow you cannot require the object from home-view-model by this `var arrNoticias = require('./home-view-model.js');`. Can you double check the path?

Comment: the path is correct because i hard-coded something in the home.view.model.js like: exports.createViewModel = "teste"; and i got the value in my home.js

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that the function is asynchronous...but there´s got be be a workaround...

Comment: Yes, how can I forget it. The function is a http request so it's an async function. That why your object is undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128080/discussion-between-japa-and-dinh-le).

Comment: Hi Dinh Le, your answer is correct but the syntax is not quite that one. I´m now getting the results, but now, another problem appeared...the xml/view file is not loading the content..i have put everything needed inside the .then function but the view doesn´t show anything...i even tryied with the code from the template that normally appears...but inside the .then function..nothing!